# Randomizing a List

Tags: vb.net, list, random, shuffle

I have this code, and it's working well. The input list is randomly shuffled very nicely.

But I'm having a little trouble understanding WHY it's working.

Specifically, what role does `oBuffer` play in all of this? Why the line at the end:

```
oBuffer(iRandom) = oBuffer(iIndex)
```

I find that when I comment it out, I end up with duplicates in the output list.

I've stepped through the code, but I'm still at a loss. What exactly is going on here?

```
  <Extension>
  Public Iterator Function Randomize(Of T)(Instance As IEnumerable(Of T), Rng As Random) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Dim oBuffer As List(Of T)
    Dim iRandom As Integer
    Dim iIndex As Integer

    Instance.ThrowIfNothing(NameOf(Instance))
    Rng.ThrowIfNothing(NameOf(Rng))

    oBuffer = Instance.ToList

    For iIndex = 0 To oBuffer.Count - 1
      iRandom = Rng.Next(iIndex, oBuffer.Count)
      Yield oBuffer(iRandom)
      oBuffer(iRandom) = oBuffer(iIndex)
    Next
  End Function
```

Comment: oBuffer is a copy of the original.  Probably used to protect the original list.  I add an answer that has an alternative FWIW.

Comment: @dbasnett The function takes an `IEnumerable` rather than a `List` as an argument.  `oBuffer` concretizes and captures the initial contents of the enumerable (which may have been deferred).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implementation of a Fisher-Yates shuffle.  There's a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) that describes the algorithm.  I believe (based on reviewing the article) that the in-place buffer is necessary in order to implement the algorithm with linear time complexity; if a separate scratch buffer were used instead, then the algorithm would be O(n²) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative (AltRandomize).  Note that this method does not require a Random instance to be passed to it.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module ModExtensions
    Public PRNG As New Random
    <Extension>
    Public Iterator Function AltRandomize(Of T)(Instance As IEnumerable(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim oBuffer As List(Of T)
        'uncomment following
        'Instance.ThrowIfNothing(NameOf(Instance))

        oBuffer = Instance.OrderBy(Function(n) PRNG.Next()).ToList

        For iIndex As Integer = 0 To oBuffer.Count - 1
            Yield oBuffer(iIndex)
        Next
        oBuffer.Clear()
    End Function

    <Extension>
    Public Iterator Function Randomize(Of T)(Instance As IEnumerable(Of T), Rng As Random) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim oBuffer As List(Of T)
        Dim iRandom As Integer
        Dim iIndex As Integer

        'Instance.ThrowIfNothing(NameOf(Instance))
        'Rng.ThrowIfNothing(NameOf(Rng))

        oBuffer = Instance.ToList

        For iIndex = 0 To oBuffer.Count - 1
            iRandom = Rng.Next(iIndex, oBuffer.Count)
            Yield oBuffer(iRandom)
            oBuffer(iRandom) = oBuffer(iIndex)
        Next
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: I like this alternate. In fact, it appears we can dispense with the `Iterator/Yield` construct altogether with it. `Return Instance.OrderBy(Function(n) PRNG.Next())`

Comment: FYI this is the second in an overloaded pair of extension methods. The first one calls this one with a new `Random` object. This one exists to counter the problem of identical sequences, as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor). *"... because the first two Random objects are created in close succession, they are instantiated using identical seed values based on the system clock and, therefore, they produce an identical sequence of random numbers."*

Comment: @InteXX - the alternative will only have one instance of Random.  If there is a need to access a Random object elsewhere in the App just use the one specified in the module.

Comment: @InteXX Use of `Iterator/Yield` depends partly on the intended usage.  If you will always want the entire list (e.g. a card game where you will always deal out the entire deck), then you don't need an iterator.  On the other hand, if you will only usually want a piece of the list, the iterator version is more efficient as it will only produce the items you request (e.g. a card game like Poker where only a portion of the deck is dealt/used).

Comment: `the alternative will only have one instance of Random` OK, I spotted that now.

Comment: `if you will only usually want a piece of the list` That helps me understand `Iterator/Yield` a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

`oBuffer` contains a copy of the original list, whatever this list contains.

The function iterates through the list as follows:

1. It starts at index zero and goes all the way until it reaches the end of the list.
2. At every loop of the `For`, a random number is generated which is basically an index number that's superior to the current item.
3. It `Yields` the random item (returns it as the next element of the new list that it's currently building, starting from index zero).
4. It takes the current item and puts it in the place previously occupied by the item which is already in the list that will be returned to you at the end of the function.

Now you must get why you got doubles by commenting out the last line: it's there to make sure that the current item will be randomized too. It's kinda like shoveling items in front of yourself to make sure that you don't forget one nor use one again once it's `Yield`ed.

Comment: That's a pretty good explanation. Note that when uncommenting the last line of the loop `oBuffer(iRandom) = oBuffer(iIndex)`, `oBuffer` contains dupes by the time the loop is exited.

Comment: I decided to accept [Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59771633) instead. The Wikipedia article he cites explains it in great detail.

Comment: YW, I appreciate the consideration.